# i have tried to scrape a table using beautifulsoup and only one line of the table appears as output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have tried to scrape the table http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=kwadukuza&country=ZA, however only the last line of the table appears

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd   

url = 'http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=kwadukuza&country=ZA'
requests.get(url)
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table_data = soup.find('table', class_ = "restable")

headers = []
for i in table_data.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)=
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

for j in table_data.find_all('tr', class_='odd'):
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in row_data]
```

Comment: This row `row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in row_data]` must be inside the `for` loop. You iterate over all `tr` tags in the table and only then try to extract text.

Comment: Also, given that you are going to use pandas, you can try reading with `pd.read_html`

Comment: HI Buran, thank you for your assistance. i have amended it as for j in table_data.find_all('tr', class_='odd'):
    row = j.text.strip()
    row_data = j.find_all('td'), however no luck. i only get the table headings

Comment: @ash84 you only want odd rows from table or all rows ??

Comment: Hi Bhavya, just the 'odd' rows

Comment: I have edited my answer please look!! @ash84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use seperate list to append `row` data to make list of list data and then use it as row for your `df`

```
all_rows=[]
for j in table_data.find_all('tr',class_="odd"):
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in row_data]
    all_rows.append(row)
```

For DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers,data=all_rows)
```

Output:

```
df.shape

(25,6)
```

Comment: thanks alot Bhavya, it turned out perfect!

Comment: You can upvote and accept as answer if possible!!

Answer (score 0):

As the comment already says, you need to put the `row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in row_data]` in the for loop. Otherwise you would just get the last entry.

In order to add the rows to the `DataFrame`, you need to make a list of all rows and put it together with the headers to a `DataFrame`. You could also append the rows to the `DataFrame`, but it is less efficient

## Solution

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd   

url = 'http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=kwadukuza&country=ZA'
requests.get(url)
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table_data = soup.find('table', class_ = "restable")

headers = []
for i in table_data.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)

data = []
for j in table_data.find_all('tr', class_='odd'):
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in row_data] # Put into the for loop
    data.append(row)

# DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers, data=data)
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you Frederick for assisting, it did print all rows, however the last 2 rows only appear in the df

Comment: I added the data to the DataFrame. It would be nice if you could up vote and accept my answer to help others.